# moment.js moment is undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, momentjs

I just updated form moment@2.1.0 to moment@2.7.0 in my Ember.js application and now I am getting an error the moment is not defined when I enter moment() into the console or include it in my scripts.

On the docs I saw "Since 2.4.0 the globally exported moment object is deprecated." which I think is the issue here but I am unsure how I can set moment globally in ember so that all of the references to moment() in our code base currently aren't broken.

I have tried updating the line where we were doing require('moment') to var moment = require('moment') but it has the same result. Even if I put a debugger directly after the var moment = ... line and then enter moment() into the console I still get that moment is undefined.

Comment: It must be something else, something conflicting with requirejs? I set up a page a few days ago with moment 2.7.0 for testing, which literally only includes `<script src="moment.min.js" ></script>` in the console typing moment returns the function ref. Any errors being thrown prior to typing moment()? Perhaps check the Network log to see if its being loaded...

Comment: What flavor of ember are you using?  if you are using a build like eak or ember-cli you need to enable `moment` in the global namespace.  did you do that already?

Comment: I traced the issue down to node's loader require module not setting the context to what moment expects. It sets the context to new Context {}. Then in moment it checks if the variable global is defined and if it is not (which is isn't in my case) then moment will set the moment variable on the "this" object, which is set to context {} rather than window. The results in moment being defined, but not on a global level. By changing the last line in the moment.js from call(this) to call(window) it now works.

Answer (score 17):

You want the [Browser](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/) section of the new Documentation.

So...

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script>
    moment().format();
</script>
```

***Edit***

Having said that, it looks like this will probably give you the same issue.

It looks like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) is trying to encourage you to use a package manager in order not to dirty the namespace with global variables.

Go read up on [CommonJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) and [AMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition), and try and factor it in to your current stack.

You should be doing something like:

```
var moment = require('moment');

moment().format();
```

But in order to use `require` you need a module system like the ones aforementioned.

***But***

The obvious fix is to rollback your version of Moment.js, so long as you don't need new functionality. How important can an update on a simple *time/date* library really be?

Comment: I need timezone's we have a payment cutoff at 10pm ET and I need to verify the cutoff is being compared to the time on the east coast not the users local machine. It's a quite a bit messier to add in all the logic to test the users timezone and then adjust dates/times to go to east coast when I could just use moment().tz('America/New_York'). It sounds like the changes that have been made to moment will cause me more updates than the amount of work on doing the logic myself.

Comment: using [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) with [RequireJS](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) shouldn't be too difficult to implement. But yes, perhaps just using the JavaScript [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) would be easier if you don't want to learn about modules.

Answer (score 2):

This happens, when before moment.js there is some package manager/loader already on:

[image: moment detects a package manager]

You can see that moment detects

1. `module.exports`
2. `define.amd`

and if there is nothing like this, then `global.moment` is assigned.

The `global` variable is actually `window`.
The `factory` variable is the `function` below representing the closure of the moment scope.

---

Two possibilities:

a) ensure that there is NO CommonJS/SystemJS... package manager/loader before `<script src="/scripts/moment-with-locales.js">`

b) follow [@shennan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520828/moment-js-moment-is-undefined#answer-24520883) and load the moment by a package manager/loader, e.g. using SystemJS:

```
SystemJS.import('/scripts/moment-with-locales.js').then(function(moment) {
    moment.locale('fr');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the possibility (a) worked for me, after three hours of effort... thank you

Comment: My hack was simply to change the line `}(this, (function () {` to `}(window, (function () {`.  There are a lot of "right ways" to do this, but ultimately on legacy systems, a quick hack doesn't do much harm.