# moment is undefined error from my Ember app's minified vendor.js

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, dependencies, momentjs

I have an Ember.js app (not ember-cli) working with grunt and bower using moment.js.

When the app runs locally, everything works fine. But when we push to production and all the dependencies get minified and concat'ed together, moment.js does not exist as a global like it normally does (Ember throws "moment is not defined"). However, if I look at vendor.js in my sources, I can see some of moment's source code (though no explicit window.moment = foo, etc.) so it's definitely making it up to production.

I've seen this problem under:
[moment.js moment is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520828/moment-js-moment-is-undefined), and have tried juking my version of moment to pre 2.4 to no avail.

Not sure how grunt compiles everything together in the build stage, but any suggestions as to how I can explicitly define moment without installing a new package manager or get around this annoying hiccup would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be resolved by using correct version of datetimepicker and momenent.js

[Download both from this site](https://cdnjs.com)

Answer (score 0):

in your `index.html` - have you included `moment.js` file in the correct section? Most likely, it should be under:

```
<!-- build:js(tmp/result) /assets/vendor.min.js -->
```

and definitely not under

```
<!-- @if dist=false -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. yeah it's was in the "<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->" block. I ended up moving it into "<!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/main.js -->" with the rest of our app's scripts which ended up solving the problem, albeit in a pretty unsatisfactory way.

Comment: why unsatisfactionary? if you don't like the concept of having the build commands in index.html, you should e.g. start using ember-cli ;)

Comment: lol sure. We were using ember-cli originally (and it handled all our dependencies wonderfully) but we ran into a whole rabbits nest of issues trying to get CORS working with our node server on heroku. seems like it'd be a simple enough operation but apparently this is something the ember-cli team is aware of.