# Installing bower dependencies with Yii2

Tags: yii2, composer-php, momentjs, bower

I want to use the [Bootstrap 3 DatePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) in my Yii2 project, for this I see it needs several dependencies like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/). But [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/) needs to be installed with [bower](https://bower.io/). It's my first web project so I'm not familiar with all these stuffs (I'm used to gradle dependencies which seems to me much easier) and I feel like lost.

I tried to used [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/) by using the "browser" version and I'm stuck again a message saying

> Cannot read property 'defineLocale' of undefined

Which seems to mean that moment.js is not correctly set up. So I came on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520828/moment-js-moment-is-undefined) saying it might be a better solution to use [bower](https://bower.io/). But as I said I feel lost trying to use it.

I ran the following command

```
bower install --save moment
```

And it was saying that I didn't had any bower.json file, so I did a

```
bower init
```

And I ended up creating this file:

```
{
  "name": "moment",
  "authors": [
    "moment"
  ],
  "description": "bower init",
  "main": ["moment.js", "locale/*.js", "min/moment-with-locales.js"],
  "keywords": [
    "moment"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "http://momentjs.com/",
  "private": false,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

I placed this file under /vendor/bower/moment and then run a `composer update` but it didn't take my "bower.json" file into account. What can I do to install moment.js and the bootstrap datepicker?

Here is where I placed my `bower.json` file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one of these widgets: [kartik-v/DatePicker](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker)

or [2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget)

or [yii\jui\DatePicker](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html)

For kartik-v/DatePicker for example you only need to use composer to install it like this:

```
$ php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker "@dev"
```

I really do not know why they show that way of installing it with composer.. I usually use:

```
composer require kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker "@dev"
```

You only need to execute this in the terminal inside the folder where your composer files are, usually the advanced folder if you are using the advanced template.

Hope this helps you

Have a good day!